# mssql_query function SQL Query in limit

Tags: php, sql, sql-server-2008

Unable to delete bulk records in " DELETE " Query,

I have table which contains IndexID, i want to delete certain indexID records, i am passing that IndexID in " Delete from TBLName Where indexID in (1,2,3,4........20000), nearly twenty thousand ID's,

But  query does not deleting even one ID also,  but if i pass 100 or 500 or 1000 IndexID, it deleting the records, as well that same query when i ran  that query in MSSQL studio, its deleting all specified ID's, but it is failed which running that query in PHP Application.

I am using PHP+MSSQL Driver, Is there any limitation exist in the MSSQL mssql_query function  ?

Comment: May be time or memory limit exceed?
What error do you have?

Comment: @MichaelSivolobov no error information, simply mssql_error returns empty .